# Creating a Rails query from a hash of user input

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm attempting to create a fairly complex search engine for a project using a variable number of search criteria. The user input is sorted into an array of hashes. The hashes contain the following information:

```
{
    :column => "",
    :value => "",
    :operator => "", # Such as: =, !=, <, >, etc.
    :and_or => "", # Two possible values: "and" and "or"
}
```

How can I loop through this array and use the information in these hashes to make an ActiveRecord WHERE query?

Comment: This seems dangerous.

Comment: Is this all you have so far?

Comment: ok, could you post your code so far ? what did you try?

Comment: Why is the question on hold? Seems pretty clear to me, and it's not dangerous if the criteria is explicitly whitelisted as in the given answer.

Comment: I don't see how I could make this question any more clear. Perhaps if someone told me what they needed to know instead of downvoting and putting my question on hold, I'd be able to explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should work:

```
query = criteria.map do |h| 
  "#{h[:column]} #{h[:operator]} ? #{h[:and_or]||''}" 
end.join(' ')

MyModel.where(query, *criteria.map { |h| h[:value] })
```

Example:

```
criteria = [{column: 'name', value: 'Jamie', operator: '=', and_or: 'and'}, 
            {column: 'age', value: 20, operator: '>' }]
```

Will result in:

```
MyModel.where("name = ? and age > ? ", "Jamie", 20)
```

I would further suggest to validate the values of `column`, `operator` and `and_or`:

```
unless criteria.all? { |h| MyModel.column_names.include? h[:column]} &&
       criteria.all? { |h| %w(= != < >).include? h[:operator] } &&
       criteria.all? { |h| ['and', 'or', nil].include? h[:and_or] }
  raise InvalidQueryError
end
```

Comment: I had to tweak it a little for my exact code, but this is more or less exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!